# How I can I link dll library to my application?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, linker-errors

When I execute my application in other computer I receive many error messages about Dll Missing but in my computer works. My question its about How Can I link correctly libraries to my project, Im using CodeBlocks.

[image: Linker Settings Screenshot]

Thanks for your replies, I have been browsing about 3h for solve it and I can´t.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: ***I receive many error messages about Dll Missing*** That means you don't have the dll in one of the folders of your `PATH` environment variable or the same folder as your executable. This has nothing to do with linker settings in Code::Blocks. This should help: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: See what DLLs are missing and transfer to this other computer where you want to execute code .

Comment: I want that the dll's come in exe, Its a problem of compiler but I can't resolve it, anyone know anything?

Comment: ***I want that the dll's come in exe*** I believe that would be a totally different question not related to this question. A simpler approach to the new problem is to use an installer like NSIS to properly install your executable and required dlls. An alternate is to not use dlls and use static libraries if possible.

Comment: There are other significantly more complicated ways using binary resources embedding the dlls inside the executable and delay loaded dlls.

Comment: Im using Curl libraries, my question its how can I add correctly this libraries to the project.

Comment: You are correctly adding the libraries (except for that you are linking to multiple versions of the same dll). However since your are using dlls they will be required to exist on whatever system you want to run your application on.

Comment: You may be able to link to just the `libcurl.a` and remove the others to remove the dll dependency  on curl